# How to map array of json data in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

am using `map`function in my code i would like to pring Qdata of below array but here it says undefined may be it is inside the array of json if am wrong please help me to correct this!
  my array structure is like this

```
    [ { _id: 201,
        user_id: 141,
        PAN: 1,
        Qdata: 023444 } ]
```

here is the map fun:

```
    var data = array.map(function(p){
    return p.Qdata
    })
```

My actual code:

```
function getTotal(req, res, next) {
    var array = [];
    var array2 = {};
    db.users.find(req.q).toArray(function(err, rest) {
        rest.map(function(ids) {
            array.push(ids._id);
        })
        var total = array.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            db.users.find(array[i]).toArray(function(err, users) {
                if (err) return next(err);
            });
            db.consumer.aggregate([{
                $unwind: "$votes"
            }, {
                $match: {
                    'consumer_id': mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(array[i])
                }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$votes.date",
                    "consumer_id": {
                        $first: "$consumer_id"
                    },
                    "vote": {
                        $sum: {
                            $cond: [{
                                '$gt': ['$votes.score', 0]
                            }, "$votes.score", 0]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }], function(err, sort_res) {
                array2.push(sort_res);
                total -= 1;
                if (total <= 0) {

                var user_obj = {};
                for (var i = rest.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var userDetails = rest[i];
               user_obj[userDetails._id] = userDetails;
            }

             var aa=array2.map(function(p){
                p.userDetails = obj[p.consumer_id];--------> here am not getting consumer_id
                return p
            })
                res.send(aa)
                }

            })
        }


    })
}
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after the `_id` property, and an end paranthesis after the last } in your second code.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu sorry i was my mistake while writing here but its correct in my code.

Comment: What doesn't work? I just tried your code in the console and it returns what it should (`023444`).

Comment: i dont know it says `undefine` for me :(

Comment: Can you post your entire code?

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu added please have a look on it!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144559/discussion-between-schuler-and-dragos-paul-marinescu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just would like to raise few points that might help you.

So for this I would like to recommend using new version of javascript **ES6** it have lot of simplified syntax changes and new updates

The output will work if you will use any number not starting from 0 in this case you will get desired output

```
  var x =[ { _id: 201,
        user_id: 141,
        PAN: 1,
        Qdata: 23444 } ]

      var data  = x.map(v => v.Qdata)
    console.log(data) // 23444
```

But if you will use any number starting form 0 like the one you have posted in you question '023444' it's treated as base 8 (octal) and would give you output as 10020 because an integer starting with 0 doesn't make sense in mathematics.